# Отображение вложеных ArrayList в TableView JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть класс:

```
Training{
    Integer id;
    GregorianCalendar date;
    String title;
    ArrayList<Exercise> exercises;
}
```

При этом в каждом объекте списка `exercises` есть свой список `ArrayList<Set> sets`.
Другими словами в каждой тренировке есть какое-то количество упражнений, и в каждом упражнении есть определенное количество подходов. 
Как это все добро вывести в `TableVeiw`?

[image: Пример нужной мне таблицы]

Comment: Для начала познакомьтесь с TreeTableView http://www.lestard.eu/2015/treetable_datamodel/

Comment: Как вы хотите, чтобы это выглядело в виде таблицы?

Comment: В конечном счете я хочу розбить это на две таблицы. В первой будут данные о тренировке (ид, дата, название), когда клацаешь на строку первой таблицы отображаются детали этой тренировки во второй таблице. В первой все уже работает. А вот со второй проблемы. 
От этого суть не меняется. Мне нужно в одной таблице вывести вложеный список. Тоесть: первая колонка - название упражнения, вторая колонка все подходы в этом упражнении (название упражнения дублируется в каждой строке), лучше без дублирования, но для начала хоть так  :)

Comment: Приложите примерный скриншот к вопросу, как вы хотите это видеть.